# issues with linking undefined reference help ! very stuck

Tags: c, visual-studio, arm, undefined-reference, atmelstudio

I am getting a "undefined reference to 'i2c_master_init' " i think this is to do some linking but not to sure how to correct ?

**UPDATE :**

iv been trying to find the answer for this for a while now. and have noticed a few bit but just not sure what i am doing wrong ! sorry it must be getting hard to read now !

This is from i2c_master.h and give me no issues

```
   static inline void i2c_master_enable(const struct i2c_master_module *const module){

   /* Sanity check of arguments */
    Assert(module);
   Assert(module->hw);

   SercomI2cm *const i2c_module = &(module->hw->I2CM);

   /* Timeout counter used to force bus state */
    uint32_t timeout_counter = 0;

    /* Wait for module to sync */
    _i2c_master_wait_for_sync(module);

    /* Enable module */
    i2c_module->CTRLA.reg |= SERCOM_I2CM_CTRLA_ENABLE;

    #if I2C_MASTER_CALLBACK_MODE == true
   /* Enable module interrupts */
   system_interrupt_enable(_sercom_get_interrupt_vector(module->hw));
   #endif

  /* Start timeout if bus state is unknown */

  while (!(i2c_module->STATUS.reg & SERCOM_I2CM_STATUS_BUSSTATE(1))) {
 timeout_counter++;
 if(timeout_counter >= (module->unknown_bus_state_timeout)) {

 /* Timeout, force bus state to idle */
 i2c_module->STATUS.reg = SERCOM_I2CM_STATUS_BUSSTATE(1);
 /* Workaround #1 */
  return;
  }
```

This is in the same file and is giving me issues

```
 enum status_code i2c_master_init(struct i2c_master_module *const module, 
 Sercom *const hw, const struct i2c_master_config *const config);
```

this is my code.....

```
 #include <asf.h>

void initialize(void)
{
system_init();
delay_init();
ioport_init();
}
//I2c slave address
#define AM2315_ADDRESS 0xB8 //temp and humity sensor
#define DATA_LENGTH 10
#define TIMEOUT 1000 //number of time to try and send the packet before it 
fails

static uint8_t write_buffer[DATA_LENGTH] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 
 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09};

 static uint8_t read_buffer[DATA_LENGTH];
 struct i2c_master_module i2c_master_instance;

  void configure_i2c_master(void)
  {
  /* Initialize config structure and software module. */
  struct i2c_master_config config_i2c_master;
  i2c_master_get_config_defaults(&config_i2c_master);

  /* Change buffer timeout to something longer. */
 config_i2c_master.buffer_timeout = 10000;

 /* Initialize and enable device with config. */
 i2c_master_init(&i2c_master_instance, SERCOM1,  &config_i2c_master);
 i2c_master_enable(&i2c_master_instance);
 }

 int main (void)
 {
 initialize();
 configure_i2c_master();
 uint8_t timeout = 0 ;

 struct i2c_master_packet packet ={
 .address = AM2315_ADDRESS,
 .data_length = DATA_LENGTH,
 .data = write_buffer,
 .ten_bit_address = false,
 .hs_master_code = 0x0,
  };

 ioport_set_pin_dir(PIN_PA27, IOPORT_DIR_OUTPUT);

 while(1)
 {
 delay_ms(1000);
 ioport_set_pin_level(PIN_PA27, true);
 delay_ms(1000);
 ioport_set_pin_level(PIN_PA27, false);

 //write buffer to slave untill success
 while(i2c_master_read_packet_wait(&i2c_master_instance, &packet) != 
 STATUS_OK){
 if (timeout++ ==TIMEOUT){
  break;
 }

 } 
 //Read from slave until success.
packet.data = read_buffer;
 while (i2c_master_read_packet_wait(&i2c_master_instance, &packet) != 
 STATUS_OK){
 if (timeout++ ==TIMEOUT){
  break;
}
}
}
}
```

**this is my output...**

```
------ Build started: Project: GccBoardProject1, Configuration: Debug ARM --

 Build started.

 Project "GccBoardProject1.cproj" (default targets):

  Target "PreBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; 
  ('$(PreBuildEvent)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').

 Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Compiler.targets" from project 
 "C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
 Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1.cproj" 
 (target "Build" depends on it):

  Task "RunCompilerTask"

 Shell Utils Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe all --jobs 4 -- 
 output-sync 

 C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
 Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\src\main.c(35,6): warning: no 
 previous prototype for 'initialize' [-Wmissing-prototypes]

 void initialize(void)

      ^~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\src\main.c(58,6): warning: no 
previous prototype for 'configure_i2c_master' [-Wmissing-prototypes]

void configure_i2c_master(void)

      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Building file: ../src/main.c

Invoking: ARM/GNU C Compiler : 6.3.1

 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\arm\arm-gnu- 
 toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"  -x c -mthumb -D__SAMD21G18A__ -DDEBUG 
-DBOARD=USER_BOARD -DARM_MATH_CM0PLUS=true -DSYSTICK_MODE - 
 DI2C_MASTER_CALLBACK_MODE=true  -I"../src/ASF/common/boards" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/utils" -I"../src/ASF/sam0/utils/header_files" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/utils/preprocessor" - 
I"../src/ASF/thirdparty/CMSIS/Include" - 
I"../src/ASF/thirdparty/CMSIS/Lib/GCC" -I"../src/ASF/common/utils" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/utils/cmsis/samd21/include" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/utils/cmsis/samd21/source" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system" 
-I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/clock/clock_samd21_r21_da_ha1" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/clock" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/interrupt" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/interrupt/system_interrupt_samd21" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/pinmux" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/power" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/power/power_sam_d_r_h" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/reset" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/reset/reset_sam_d_r_h" - 
I"../src/ASF/common2/boards/user_board" -I"../src" -I"../src/config" - 
I"../src/ASF/common2/services/delay" - 
I"../src/ASF/common2/services/delay/sam0" - 
I"../src/ASF/common/services/ioport" -I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/sercom" - 
I"../src/ASF/sam0/drivers/sercom/i2c"  -O1 -fdata-sections -ffunction- 
sections -mlong-calls -g3 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -c -pipe -fno-strict- 
aliasing -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit- 
function-declaration -Wpointer-arith -std=gnu99 -ffunction-sections -fdata- 
sections -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wformat=2 -Wimplicit-int -Wmain - 
Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wtrigraphs -Wunused - 
Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wbad- 
function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return  -Wmissing- 
declarations -Wformat -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-deprecated- 
declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wlong-long - 
Wunreachable-code -Wcast-align --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -MD -MP - 
MF "src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o"   -o "src/main.o" 
"../src/main.c" 

Finished building: ../src/main.c

src/main.o: In function `configure_i2c_master':

C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\src\main.c(69,1): error: 
undefined reference to `i2c_master_init'

src/main.o: In function `main':

C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\src\main.c(103,1): error: 
undefined reference to `i2c_master_read_packet_wait'

collect2.exe(0,0): error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [GccBoardProject1.elf] Error 1

Building target: GccBoardProject1.elf

Invoking: ARM/GNU Linker : 6.3.1

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\arm\arm-gnu- 
toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -o GccBoardProject1.elf  
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/sercom/sercom.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/sercom/sercom_interrupt.o 
src/ASF/common2/services/delay/sam0/systick_counter.o 
src/ASF/common2/boards/user_board/init.o 
src/ASF/common/utils/interrupt/interrupt_sam_nvic.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/clock/clock_samd21_r21_da_ha1/clock.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/clock/clock_samd21_r21_da_ha1/gclk.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/interrupt/system_interrupt.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/pinmux/pinmux.o 
src/ASF/sam0/drivers/system/system.o 
src/ASF/sam0/utils/cmsis/samd21/source/gcc/startup_samd21.o 
src/ASF/sam0/utils/cmsis/samd21/source/system_samd21.o 
src/ASF/sam0/utils/syscalls/gcc/syscalls.o src/main.o   -mthumb -Wl,- 
Map="GccBoardProject1.map" --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--start-group - 
larm_cortexM0l_math -lm  -Wl,--end-group - 
L"../src/ASF/thirdparty/CMSIS/Lib/GCC"  -Wl,--gc-sections -mcpu=cortex- 
m0plus -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--cref -mthumb - 
T../src/ASF/sam0/utils/linker_scripts/samd21/gcc/samd21g18a_flash.ld  

C:\Users\benvo\Documents\Atmel 
Studio\7.0\GccBoardProject1\GccBoardProject1\Debug\Makefile(333,1): error: 
recipe for target 'GccBoardProject1.elf' failed

The command exited with code 2.

Done executing task "RunCompilerTask" -- FAILED.

Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "GccBoardProject1.cproj" -- 
FAILED.

Done building project "GccBoardProject1.cproj" -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.

 ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

TAGS:
Tools, Atmel Software Framework (ASF) and Atmel Start (ASFv4), all 
architectures
```

Comment: Your question is not in readable format. Please correct the formatting, indent your code for better readability.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not in your source code, but in your project settings. You haven’t included the .lib or .dll file, or you did it wrong. Seeing all your source code won’t help us debug that.

Comment: sorry i have just formatted bit i hope this helps. Ok the strange thing is i have some functions working in the same file and some not (i2c_master.h) do you have any iders what i can check im still fairly green to this. thanks you for your time !

Comment: Some of the "functions" that work may be inlined or #define macros, or they may be defined in another library that you DO include correctly.

Comment: ok thank you for the guidance il take a looking my includes.

Comment: just added #include <asf.h>
#include <i2c_common.h>
#include <i2c_master.h> but still no luck. :(

Comment: @BenVolz Adding #include lines will almost certainly not help with this problem.  You need to add files (modules, libraries) to the project in your IDE.

Comment: all sorted now thanks for you help. I was a issues with missing .c files i had to remove part of the framework with ASF wizard and them put back